# MySQL add where clause if field is not null

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a `news` table, and I want to get all the `news` that are started but not ended yet by filtering by the columns `start_at` & `end_at` :

```
"select * from `news` where `start_at` <= NOW() and `end_at` >= NOW()"
```

or as I'm doing in Laravel :

```
$news = News::where("start_at", '<=', date("Y-m-d"))
            ->where("end_at", '>=', date("Y-m-d"))->get();
```

But I also want to ignore filtering by the column `end_at` if it is NULL, so if the column is NULL I want the result to be displayed as if I only used this query :

```
"select * from `news` where `start_at` <= NOW()"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the table strcuture with some data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query to select dates where field is NULL or field date value is not greater than another date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642362/mysql-query-to-select-dates-where-field-is-null-or-field-date-value-is-not-great)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use AND/OR logical operators, alongwith [`IS NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) comparison operator. Query in MySQL would be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM news 
WHERE start_at <= NOW() AND 
      (end_at >= NOW() OR end_at IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

If `end_at` is indexed  i rather would rather rewrite Madhur Bhaiya's answer

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM news 
WHERE start_at <= NOW() AND 
      (end_at >= NOW() OR end_at IS NULL)
```

as

**Query rewite**

```
SELECT * FROM news 
WHERE
    start_at <= NOW()
  AND 
    end_at >= NOW()
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM news 
WHERE
    start_at <= NOW()
  AND
     end_at IS NULL
```

Because `OR` tends to optimize much worse then using a `UNION ALL` approach. 
Oracle database does optimization trick native in the optimizer, still waiting until MySQL also get this optimization trick native in the optimizer as MySQL is owned by Oracle corp.

Comment: Interesting insight. Although it seems that `OR` is one of the basic things in programming, and should have been taken care off by MySQL. You will need to add `AND start_at <= NOW()` in your second query (withing UNION)

Comment: *"You will need to add AND start_at <= NOW() in your second query (withing UNION)"* indeed i forgot the `AND start_at <= NOW()` in the second select thank you @MadhurBhaiya

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `Carbon`:

```
$news = News::where("start_at", '<=', Carbon::now())
             ->when('end_at' !== null, function($query){
                  $query->where("end_at", '>=', Carbon::now())
             })
             ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the union Operator, we can do something like this:

```php
$news = News::whereNotNull("end_at")
            ->where("start_at", '<=', date("Y-m-d"))
            ->where("end_at", '>=', date("Y-m-d"))
            ->union
            (

               News::whereNull("end_at")
                   ->where("start_at", '<=', date("Y-m-d"))

            )->get();
```